# Closing connection to github application

Tags: git, api, github

I want to use a web application that I found on github, but the problem I want to secure it more. More like closing it's connection to anywhere else. For the sake of closing/securing it's source. Hence, I can use it whenever I want without worrying about if the publisher remove/modify the source.

Please guide me to the correct path if what I've said is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the repository from Github as a `.zip` file.  This won't create any link between your computer and the remote repo.  However, you won't be able to `git fetch` any of the updates to the source code.

Comment: Actually I've downloaded that master.zip, but there is an API php file in there, and it's filled with git and stuff. In case, I've done that using git clone, is it possible to close that connection? I don't really need their updates In order to be safe =)

Comment: Just delete the Git directory.  The `.git` directory contains a file called `config`.  This file would contain the "connection" to the remote repository.  Therefore, if you delete the entire Git folder after downloading the `.zip` file you will remove this "connection".